# css: make ":after content " clickble in all browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I make css `"content:"` clickable in all browsers? It does work on Firefox, IE, but not in Chrome.

***HTML***

```
<div class="letters" id="letter_b">B<a id="success_b"></a></div>
```

***CSS***

```css
.letters a:after {
    color: #303030;
    content: "clickable text";
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 200px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the link `<a>` display as an `inline-block` element - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5WQJE/)